# how to write and read data from smart card using java card apdu

Tags: java, byte, smartcard, javacard, apdu

I have written an applet and installed it in smart card. But I don't know how to read and write data to smart card?

```
private void readName(APDU apdu) throws ISOException
{
    byte[] apduBuffer = apdu.getBuffer();
    for (byte i=0; i<userName.length; i++)
    {
        apduBuffer[5+i] = userName[(byte)i] ;
    }
    apdu.setOutgoing();
    apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)userName.length);
    apdu.sendBytes((short)5, (short)userName.length);
}
```

Is it right code to read data from smart card?

please tell me how to write data to smart card using javacard.

Comment: I assume that you don't want to read and write data from the smart card - instead you are asking how to send data from the host to an applet on the card and after processing on-card send the response data back to the host application.

Comment: yes,can you tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.actually I am using eclipse as a editor java card plugin are install in it.when I run program on Smart Card it install latest applet on previous applet every time.To see result we can use pyapdu tool it is very good. thanks for all the response..

Comment: I don't understand much of that answer (and, actually, I don't understand much of your question either). What plugin are you using? What is a pyapdu tool?

Comment: I installed JAVACARD Plugin and JCOP Plugin in Eclipse.When I was trying to run a program with hardware.It replace my latest Applet with previous Applet.so i lost data in smartcard every time i run program and did not understand that my program working or not.for that i found one tool that show the data from smart card.and then i know the program is working.

Comment: OK, now it makes sense to me. Thanks for reporting back Sachin. Java Card does perform garbage collection when you remove an Applet instance, and that does indeed wipe the heap (in persistent memory) clean. Without using special API's, that's the only storage area that you've got to your disposal.

Answer (score 1):

Your card is either contact or contactless. Since you say you have already installed the applet, I assume you have the keys to the card.

If so, in order to communicate with your card you will need to do the following:

1. First authenticate with the Security Domain to which the applet is installed
2. Select the AID of the applet
3. use SEND  to send data to applet.

And in the response, you will see the bytes you are sending from the Applet:

```
apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)userName.length);
apdu.sendBytes((short)5, (short)userName.length);
```

If you need anything more, you will need to provide more details on what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: the problem is that when I send data to applet in second time it override the data on previous data? and tell me how to read data from applet?

Comment: Whenever you send data to Applet, applet's process method along with the APDU would be called. So in this process method you will store any data that you would want to. Could you tell what is the environment you are working with? - What kind of a card (Contact/Contact less), it's manufacturer, GP version support, what reader you are using and are you trying to communicate over PC/SC on J2SE etc. Complete code and more information on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @KiranKuppa there is generally no need to authenticate with a Security Domain before executing a SELECT, the SELECT makes the authentication actually rather pointless, as the Security Domain will be deselected.

Comment: @owlstead Oh yeah, there might not be any need to authenticate with SD. But usually, the commercial applications developed are such that security level would be defined by the SD for external communication. Well, I have personally NEVER come across the case when it isn't required to perform mutual auth with SD