# can some one tell me how to read data in smart card using java card? I have this code i am using java card 2.2

Tags: java, byte, smartcard, javacard, apdu

I am new to java card.

i have this code.....so please tell me how to read data from smart card using java card

```
        private void readName(APDU apdu) throws ISOException
    {
      byte[] apduBuffer = apdu.getBuffer();
      for (byte i=0; i<userName.length; i++)
      {
        apduBuffer[5+i] = userName[(byte)i] ;
      }
      apdu.setOutgoing();
      apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)userName.length);
      apdu.sendBytes((short)5, (short)userName.length);
    }
```

Comment: and where did you get that code? taking someone else code won't make you understand if you don't know what it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to write and read data from smart card using java card apdu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264850/how-to-write-and-read-data-from-smart-card-using-java-card-apdu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common mechanism to read data from files in smart card is:

1. select the file (EF), follow the rules, you can't blindly select as in desktop computer filesystem
2. send read binary/record depending on EF type (read binary for transparent EF, read record for linear fixed/cyclic EF)
3. send get response to get the EF contents

Comment: can you tell me syntax for this?

Comment: than you for you response.just tell me how to write numbers from 1 to 5 into smart card using java card? and how to retrieve it from smart card using java card?

Comment: what syntax? use that APDU thing. read binary is A0 B0, read record is A0 B2, while get response is A0 C0. every communication in standard smartcard is done via APDU commands. check ISO-7816 for details.

Comment: just tell me,where can i find all this in detail or from start?

Comment: i know every communication in standard smartcard is done via APDU commands.but i don't know specific commands and how to use them?

Comment: ISO-7816, I've stated it above. Read part 4: http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4.aspx

Comment: i didn,t get response after passing a command.if i send (send "00da000003") da for read and 03 = no of byte to be read.then where i get response.

Comment: it depends on your terminal. terminals that implement the standard correctly should always return response data (if exists) + status word after each command execution. now the next question: what do you use to communicate with the card? Also, have you load the code to your card (to the OS to be precise)?

Comment: yes,I install applet into card.Actually it working correctly.Thank you for all the support.

Comment: An addition, before step 2: fulfill the access rights/conditions for read (i.e. performing verify pin)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find an integrated development environment to write your javacard simulation code card, after burn into real card in the code.
Free integrated debugging environment could go to the www.javacos.com.